# database file is not able to create connection

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to connect to mysql database in php myadmin through OOP process in PHP. But my connection is not created. I checked with  my database name in phpmyadmin also it is ok. But don't know why my connection is not created.below is my code.

```
<?php
class db{
    public $host = 'localhost';
    public $username = 'root';
    public $password = '';
    public $dbname = 'oop';

    public function __construct(){
        $con = new mysqli($this->host,$this->username,$this->password,$this->dbname);
    }
}
if(isset($con)){
    echo "<center><h1 style='color:green;'>Db is conected</h1></center>";
}else{
    echo "<center><h1 style='color:red;'>Db is not conected</h1></center>";
}
$obj = new db;
?>
```

but i am getting "Db is not connected". Please correct me where  i have done mistake

Comment: For one, it will always return false because you are using an undefined variable, which is `$con`

Comment: now i got it thank you buddy

Answer (score 1):

In the class, create a new property. Eg.

```
public $con;
```

Then in your construct function,  have it as

```
$this->con  = new mysqli('','','',''); //database credentials
```

Then you can check for successful connection as in

```
if  ( $this->con === false)  { // add in construct function 
//connection failed
}
```

Or you can create an instance of the class and check for successful connection

```
$obj  = new db(); // __construct() has already been executed 
 if ( $obj->con  === false) {
 //connection failed 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `$con = new mysqli($this->host,$this->username,$this->password,$this->dbname);` into `$this->con = new mysqli($this->host,$this->username,$this->password,$this->dbname);`

and create the instance `$obj = new db;` before accessing it. so change your code like this

```
$obj = new db;
if($obj->con!=null){
echo "<center><h1 style='color:green;'>Db is conected</h1></center>";
}else{
echo "<center><h1 style='color:red;'>Db is not conected</h1></center>";
}
```